# Markdown Double Table issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown

I wrote a one javascript markdown editor. When I click twice the table, 2 tables are create. But I have some problem for that. That tables are merging. How to avoid this problem?

**Input:**

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```

**Output:**

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First | row |
| Second | row |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a blank line to separate them:

```
| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |

| A header | Another header |
| -------- | -------------- |
| First    | row            |
| Second   | row            |
```